# Layout as selector item in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use text view as `CheckBox` background and set different color for each state. Some how I managed to get it with Java. But I don't think it is the
proper way. Is there any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Implement onClickListener to your textview, something like:

```
int ispressed = 0;
TextView txtview = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.textview1);
txtview.setOnClickListener(new new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if(ispressed=0){
                  //CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR
                   ispressed=1;
             }else{
                //RESTORE BACKGROUND COLOR
                }   
                }
                 });
```